# Why can't I get a data array from controllers to view in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a model, controller and view file.

**Model**

```
  public function isletme_bilgileri($yetki){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('isletme_bilgileri');
    $this->db->where($yetki);
    $query=$this->db->get();
   return  $result = $query->result();
```

**Controller**

```
 $this->load->model('Bilgi_Model');
          $result = $this->Bilgi_Model->isletme_bilgileri($this->session->user_sess['yetki']);
          $isletme_bilgileri=array(
          'id'              =>$result->id,
          'isletme_adi'     =>$result->isletme_adi,
                  );
          
   
    // işletme bilgisi Çekildi //        
            
    $this->load->view('admin/_header', $isletme_bilgileri);
```

**View** (_header.php)

```
<span class="logo-lg"><b><?=$this->isletme_bilgileri('isletme_adi')?></b></span>
```

But I'm not getting the data in the view file.

**Error**

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: admin/Home.php
>
> Line Number: 19
>
> Backtrace: File: C:\wamp64\www\apartman_ys\application\controllers\admin\Home.php
> Line: 19
> Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\wamp64\www\apartman_ys\index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

Answer (score 0):

CI passes variables to view as an assoc array:

```
$data = array('car' => 'blue');
$this->load->view('index', $data);
```

Then in your view:

```
<span><?=$car;?>//outputs blue</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with your model. Check whether the row is being returned on for the query you are executing. You can get the last executed query in CI using this.

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

echo this in your controller copy the query and paste it into phpMyAdmin or Whatever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
In Controller
$data['isletme_bilgileri']=array(
          'id'              =>$result->id,
          'isletme_adi'     =>$result->isletme_adi,
                  );
$this->load->view('admin/_header', $data)

<span class="logo-lg"><b><?=$isletme_bilgileri['isletme_adi']?></b></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes  ı fix it
$result variable must be $result[0]

now the actual code is this ;

```
$result = $this->Bilgi_Model->isletme_bilgileri();
            $data=array(
                'id'=>$result[0]->id,
                'isletme_adi'=>$result[0]->isletme_adi,
                'isletme_kisa_ad'=>$result[0]->isletme_kisa_ad
            );
```